# QtMobility bearer management

Tags: qt, mobile, symbian, qt-mobility

I'm creating a Qt Symbian application and need to connect to internet. In some way I need to let the user choose a connection ONCE when the app starts or use the DEFAULT connection if that is enabled.

Before I just used qt_SetDefaultIap() to set the connection on start. It worked perfect but now I need to use QtMobility instead. I have tried the following in QMainWindow when my app starts:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;

const bool selectIap = (manager.capabilities()& QNetworkConfigurationManager::CanStartAndStopInterfaces);
QNetworkConfiguration defaultIap = manager.defaultConfiguration();

if(!defaultIap.isValid() && (!selectIap && defaultIap.state() != QNetworkConfiguration::Active))
    {
    // let the user know that there is no access point available
    }

session = new QNetworkSession(defaultIap,this);
session->open();
```

But there must be something I'm missing as the application always asks the user to choose connection each time it uses internet not just once as I want. And even if I choose a connection the application asks three times. EDIT: It works on Nokia 5800 but not on N97.

This seems to be a problem for many people as it has been discussed before:

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?196396-how-to-use-QNetworkConfigurationManager-to-handle-access-point

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?199401-How-to-use-bearer-management-to-select-access-point

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?199472-How-can-I-set-the-best-one-access-point-as-default

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: That's which Qt version?

Answer (score 0):

if your phone settings are set as 'Always ask' in (5800) Menu -> Settings -> Destinations -> Options -> Default connection, then QNetworkConfigurationManager.defaultConfiguration() will return the UserChoice configuration, which will always popup a query.

If you wish to control which access point is really used, then you could enumerate/list the configurations (QNetworkConfigurationManager::allConfigurations(), choose the one you want, and then create a QNetworkSession based on it and call QNetworkSession::open(). After that if you instantiate and use e.g. QNetworkAccessManager to perform web queries, they should use that configuration "automatically".